# fullPage.js tap not working on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, fullpage.js

Here is the [link](http://www.pixquare.com/portfolio/saturn/) for testing:

When you click on the moon on the upper right ( about us ) or the arrows on each side of the screen, it slides to the next item. Works fine in desktop. But in mobile devices, tap doesn't seem to work.

Any workarounds for this? I don't have any options set for the plugin. Just a simple:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $.fn.fullpage(); });
```

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem. You should never specify the width of the `slide` classed elements. It will cause problems in Mobile Browsers.

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1):

that because the link is not occupying the whole image. so you have to outer the image with a div having the same width and height of image.

```
<a class="slide-link" href="#">
<div style="width: 86px; height: 86px;">
<img class="moon" src="assets/images/about-us-moon.png" alt="About Us - Moon">
</div></a>
```